# JavaScript: Retry request on fail and continue normal app flow

Tags: javascript

**Quick context:**

The user has a problem with the network and I need to repeat requests to the server to continue loading app instead of showing an error.

**Existing code in the app:**

```js
  ajaxPostWithRootData = function (url, rootData) {
    //prepare request

    var request = decoratorFunction(
      $.ajax({
       //standard data required to send request
      })
    )
      .done(function (result) {
        // normal flow
      })
      .fail(function (e) {
        //I want to repeat call after 1 second
      });

    return request;
  };
```

**Example call:**

```js
    return ajaxPostWithRootData(url, data)
      .done(function (result) {
      //do some stuff       
      })
      .fail(function (e) {
        //hide loading, show error message
      });
  };
```

I thought to write in `fail()` something like that:

```js
//repeatOnFail is a new function's param to prevent infinite loop 
if (shouldRepeatOnConnectionProblem(repeatOnFail, e)) {
    setTimeout(() => ajaxPostWithRootData(url, rootData, false), 1000);
}
```

Unfortunately JS works asynchronously here and even I get success response in second request, it's too late because app executes code from second `fail()`.

Do you know how to change this code to "back" to the correct flow when I got a success response after the second call?

My knowledge about JS is poor, so even I know have an idea how to fix it, I don't know how to implement a solution ;/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would like to invoke `$.ajax({..})` with a fixed configuration and, if that first invocation fails, immediately retry the `$.ajax({..})` request with the same configuration, in which case the following changes to `ajaxPostWithRootData` should achieve what you require:

```
var ajaxPostWithRootData = function(url, rootData) {

    // Define reusable function that sets up and invokes
    // ajax request
    var doRequest = function() {
        return decoratorFunction(
            $.ajax({
            //standard data required to send request
        }))
    }      

    // Return a promise that is controlled by this deferred behavior      
    return $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
        doRequest()
        .fail(function (){
            doRequest ()
            .fail(function () {
                // On fail after second attempt, throw error
                // to external app flow
                deferred.reject();
            }).done(function (result){
                // If second attempt succeed, continue external
                // app flow                    
                deferred.resolve(result);
            });
         })
        .done(function (result){
            // If first attempt succeed, continue external 
            // app flow
            deferred.resolve(result);
        });
   }).promise();
};
```

There updates should also work nicely with your external code and preserve the overall flow of events that you're after.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer!

I tried your code but it doesn't work as I expected:

1. '`catch` is not a function' so I need to use `fail`

2. You skipped delay (it's not a problem in PoC)

3. I tried this solution and code execute the second `fail()` without waiting for second response from server.

Comment: Sorry just updating from phone so formatting is a bit messy but the deffered object might be a better fit here